# As far as I know, you can't compile Swift on Windows, so how does SwiftStub compile code on Windows?

Tags: windows, swift, browser

I initially thought that there was some way to be able to run Swift on Windows using emulators, or some other program that allowed Windows to compile and run Swift, but after browsing here a few times I learned that there is no(legal) way to do it. So how is it possible that you can do this at SwiftStub thru your internet browser?

You can check it out here:http://swiftstub.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily! They compile and run code on a **Macintosh Server** on their end, and just feed you the result in a web-based app. *You're* not running the code, they are. You just get to see the end result.

Comment: Oh man, wishful thinking/foolishness lead me to believe that I still had a chance to run Swift on Windows lol, thanks for your reply!

Comment: Ahhaha seriously, I get it! No problem! Wanna mark as solved so you can damn the hopes of the next one too?

Comment: Is Swift really coming to open source? Or you pulling my leg?